# Create a custom record type in NetSuite via SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, suitecloud

Is it possible to create a custom **record type** in NetSuite via SuiteScript? If so, how would this be done? I couldn't find any documentation on this.

I want to be able to do the following programmatically that is typically done via the UI.

```
Customization > Lists, Records & Fields > Record Types > New Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a custom record type from SuiteScript. From the NetSuite Docs:

> The NetSuite UI enables you to create custom record types and work
> with instances of those types. You cannot use SuiteScript to create a
> custom record type or make changes to an existing custom record type.
> However, you can use SuiteScript to interact with instances of an
> existing custom record type.
>
> For example, suppose your system had a custom record type called
> Feature. Each instance of that record type would be a feature record.
> You could use SuiteScript to update an existing feature record, delete
> a feature record, or create a new feature record. However, you could
> not use SuiteScript to alter the Feature custom record type.